# Error in join result from two tables in Laravel Eloquent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

I am currently trying to make a relation between multiple tables.

**education_institutions**

```
id  institution_name  country  city    
1    ABC College       UK      London
```

**user_education**

```
id  user_id  institution_id  grade   year  
1    1         1              3.2    2010
```

And the relationships are

```
class UserEducation extends Model {

  public function educationInstitution()
    {
       return $this->hasMany(EducationInstitution::class,'institution_id');
    }
}

class EducationInstitution extends Model{

   public function userEducation()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(UserEducation::class);
    }
}
```

And finally in controller:

```
class UserEducationController extends Controller
{
    public function getUserEducation()
    {
        $userEducation = UserEducation::with('education_institutions')
            ->where('user_id',auth()->user()->id)
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
            ->get();


        return response()->json([
            'userEducation' => $userEducation
        ]);
    }
}
```

It giving the following error:

> *Call to undefined relationship [education_institutions] on model [App\Models\UserEducation].*

I was expecting a response like:

```
{
  "userEducation": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "user_id": 1,
      "institution_id": 1,
      "grade": "3.49",
      "institution_name": "ABC College"
      "country":"UK",
      "city":"London"
    }
}
```

How to solve it ?

Comment: try to give your relation a name $this->hasMany(EducationInstitution::class,'institution_id')->as("education_institutions");

Comment: if you've named your relationship method as `educationInstitution` why would call it with an underscore in-between. do this `::with('educationInstitution')`

Comment: I think your relationship is wrong On  UserEducation model

Comment: Please Tell me your relationship logic between those table. I think i can help you..

Answer (score 0):

Well, there was a little error in my relationship as @Eahiya said. Further more I corrected `::with('educationInstitution')` as @Sumit suggested.

My current code is:

```
class UserEducation extends Model {

  public function educationInstitution()
    {
       return $this->belogsTo(EducationInstitution::class,'institution_id');
    }
}

class EducationInstitution extends Model{

   public function userEducation()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(UserEducation::class);
    }
}
```

and the controller:

```
public function getUserEducation()
    {
        $userEducation = UserEducation::with('educationInstitution')
            ->where('user_id',auth()->user()->id)
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
            ->get();


        return response()->json([
            'userEducation' => $userEducation
        ]);
    }
```

And it's working fine now.